# How to exclude files from Ember build?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a project build on Ember that uses [ember-engines](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines) library.

My goal - is to exclude some files from in-repo-addons (engines).

I tried [ember-cli-funnel](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-funnel). It allows to exclude files from the application but not from engines.

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  funnel: {
    enabled: true,
    exclude: ['app-name/templates/components/develop/**']
  }
});
```

The example of the project structure:

```
    ├── app/
    │   ├── controllers/
    │   ├── routes/
    │   └── templates/
    │       └── components/
    │           └──develop/
    └── lib
        ├── engine-1
        ├── engine-2
        └── engine-3
            └── addon/
                └── services/
                    └──debug.js
```

I tried different ways to exclude but with no luck.

```
[
  'lib/engine-3/addon/services/debug.js',
  'app-name/..lib/engine-3/addon/services/debug.js',
  'app-name/addons/engine-3/addon/services/debug.js'
]
```

So the question - how can be excluded files from in-repo-addons on build step?

Comment: This seems to be the responsibility of the engine's build instead of the consuming apps, have you tried filtering it out at that level?